# Save data in child table with parent table having composite keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, child-process

I wonder why it is not working.

I am using ASP.NET MVC having dbcontext to contact with database.

I have two tables.
Table A and Table B

Table A has multiple columns from that there are three columns i.e. Email, Year and Month which are primary keys  / composite keys.

Table B has a 5 columns from which one column is the TableAid that is use to store the auto incremented first column from the TableA without relationship as a foreign key, just store the id.

I pass the details from the view to controller as a one object i.e. TableA class and TableA has a list collection of TableB having multiple values.

Now I store the first TableA data first and than by taking id of the TableA and store TableB's data one by one.

Here in above process I got a exception while storing the details in TableB.

i.e. 
Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'Year'.
Invalid column name 'Month'.

Which are composite keys.

I am not able to store child tables details.

Can anyone having any solutions for this?

```
public class TableA
{
//all fields get set

virtual public ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
}
```